# Регистрация в Developer Console на Google Play для юридического лица

Tags: android, google-play, playmarket

Столкнулись с такой проблемой, заказчик из другой страны. Сам отказывается делать аккаунт. Приняли решение, что будем делать за заказчика. Провели оплату, и уже после заметили, что указали на этапе оплаты собственную страну(Google говорит, что данный параметр теперь уже изменить нельзя, необходимо создавать новый аккаунт)
Может у кого есть практический опыт, чтобы не наступить на одни и те же "грабли" дважды. Какие еще проблемы могут возникнуть после регистрации на юридическое лицо и создания платежного профиля, так как приложение будет с IAP. Не будет ли проблемы, что оплачиваем картой не относящейся к заказчику?

Answer (score 1):

> Сам отказывается делать аккаунт

Раз заказчику всё равно, то вам то чего переживать?

В целом, вы можете регистрировать на любую страну, на любого пользователя. А оплачивать картой можно с произвольными данными, даже близко не относящимся к данным аккаунта. Проверено.